# Android, passing data into new Activity (bundle)

Tags: android

In my app, I want the users to see a list of cities, select the city, then see people associate with that city.

So, I have this to get the data:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);


    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.orderByAscending(ParseConstants.KEY_LOCATION);
    query.setLimit(1000);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

            if (e == null) {
                // Success
                mMidwifeLocation = users;
                String[] locations = new String[mMidwifeLocation.size()];
                String check;
                int i = 0;
                for(ParseUser user : mMidwifeLocation) {
                    check=user.getString("city");
                    if(check!=null){
                        if(!Arrays.asList(locations).contains(check)){
                            locations[i] = user.getString("city");
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        SearchingMidwife.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,
                        locations);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchingMidwife.this);
                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                        .setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

And this to pass the selected item to the new activity:

```
@Override protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) { super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    SparseBooleanArray checked = l.getCheckedItemPositions();

    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
        // Item position in adapter
        position = checked.keyAt(i);
        // Add sport if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
        if (checked.valueAt(i))
            selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position));
    }

    String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
        outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MidwifeResultList.class);

    // Create a bundle object
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putStringArray("selectedItems", outputStrArr);

    // Add the bundle to the intent.
    intent.putExtras(b);

    // start the ResultActivity
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

When I try it though, the app stops with an error once I select the item...

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: android.bignerdranch.com.mobilemidwife,
>   PID: 31604 java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.bignerdranch.com.mobilemidwife.SearchingMidwife.onListItemClick(SearchingMidwife.java:169)

Which points to this:

```
if (checked.valueAt(i)) selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position)); }
```

I declare adapter before onCreate:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter;
```

I assume this is the same adapter that is used in OnResume...something is not quite right, not sure what that would be.  It seems like the adapter from onResume is not being passed into onResume, as it is null.

I am a bit new to this, so trying to learn this as best I can; I apologize if the problem is something missed that is simple.

Thanks so much for your help/insights

Michael Cabus

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    SearchingMidwife.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,
                    locations);
```

This is creating a `local` variable which is only scoped inside the method.

Change it to

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    SearchingMidwife.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,
                    locations);
```

by removing the leading `ArrayAdapter<String>` and that should fix this particular problem.

**Update:**

May I suggest using a different coding style such as putting leading underscore to your class member variables so that it's easier to detect these problems in the future? it's only a suggestion but I've found it immensely helpful to adapt this particular style.

What I mean is to for instance declare your variable like

ArrayAdapter _adapter;

in your class and then set it like this:

```
_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    SearchingMidwife.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,
                    locations);
```

Now every time you see "_", it's indicating that it's a member variable and not a local variable (since you would declare those without the leading underscore).

Just a personal suggestion. Up to you to adopt it or leave it.

Comment: I typically use an m in front of all member variables..I left it off this one, but I do this in all cases normally...I find it helpful too.